# How to add a mini STATIC page preview for a link embedded in a webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, web, hyperlink

Most of the tutorials and answers to questions refer to the iframe html tag which shows a live usable preview but I'm looking for a way to add a mini static image of the page that the link leads to. Is it possible? if so then how?

Comment: [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) comes to mind as worthy of investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML to Canvas http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

First, create a canvas from the static page. You can add the canvas tag that renders the image of the static page.